# Get Linked Elements that Appear on Schedule Revit API

Tags: api, schedule, autodesk, revit

Using the Revit API (2017 and above), is there any way to get a list of linked elements that appear on the schedule (including filters, phase filters, etc).

Currently, if you query a ViewSchedule using the FilteredElementCollector, it will return N Elements (e.g. Windows, Doors) and M RevitLinkInstances. However, the RevitLinkInstance does not list out the actual Element that appears in the linked model. Is there a way to query in RevitLinkInstance in the scope of the ViewSchedule? Or a similar solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it to work by passing the Schedule Id to a new fileteredElementCollector like this:

```
schedule = doc.ActiveView
scheduledElements = list(FilteredElementCollector(doc, schedule.Id))

allElements = []

for element in scheduledElements:
    if element.Category.Name == 'RVT Links':
        linkedElements = list(FilteredElementCollector(element.GetLinkDocument(), schedule.Id))
        for linkedElement in linkedElements:
            allElements.Add(linkedElement)
    else:
        allElements.Add(element)

for element in allElements:
    print element
```

Let me know if that worked for you aswell